# H.264 - Green frames when streaming over TCP using FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264, flv

I am using FC23 machine and FFMPEG version is 2.8.10

Using below command, I can stream flv over tcp successfully and able to receive it successfully at receiver side as well. I play it using vlc player. Both audio and video are played well.

> ./ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -framerate 15 -i :0.0 -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:1 -vcodec libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -acodec aac -strict -2 -ar 48000 -ab 96k -f flv -metadata streamName=naseeb.sdp tcp://127.0.0.1:6666

But in actually i need to do this using an application. So i wrote an application in 'C' language. 
I have done following things in the application.

```
 1. Open `AVOutputFormat` using below API
    fmt = av_guess_format("flv", NULL , NULL);
 2. Get `AVFormatContext` using below API
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&oc, fmt, NULL, NULL);
 3. Then added streams(audio and video) using required APIs
 4. Then open codecs using required APIs
 5. Then set the output using below API
    ret = avio_open(&oc->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
```

(A) If I need to **write** flv into a file on system then I provide `filename` in step 5 as `muxer.flv`.

- result : When I play `muxer.flv` using VLC player both video and audio are played well

(B) If I need to **stream** flv over tcp then I provide `filename` as `tcp://127.0.0.1:6666`.

- result : When it is streamed over network then Green frames are shown for video (yet audio works very well). Is there an extra setting required when I need to stream it over network?

I have no doubt on Receiver side as it works very well with `FFmpeg` utility (command mentioned above).
Currently I have downloaded ffmpeg 2.8.10 source code and looking into `ffmpeg.c` file for some extra setting. Till now I have not found anything helpful.

Please suggest something why Green frames shown when flv is sent on network where it works well when dump on system hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue.

Earlier, i was calling `avformat_write_header` before extracting extradata which is required for flv container.

Now first i update `st->codec->extradata` and `st->codec->extradata_size` then i call `avformat_write_header` api and everything works fine.

Comment: how do you update `st->codec->extradata` and `st->codec->extradata_size`. can you share some code sample?

Comment: pkt.data is the first frame. `st->codec->extradata_size = oc->streams[0]->parser->parser->split(oc->streams[0]->codec,pkt.data,pkt.size);
memcpy(st->codec->extradata, pkt.data, st->codec->extradata_size);`